# Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package

Tags: windows-7, wix, installation, wix3.6

I am using WiX 3.6 to create my application setup. I have bundled two MSI packages in one bootstrapper, and everything is fine until I install the bootstrapper on a Windows7 PC. The setup works fine on a Windows XP machine.

After installation starts in Windows 7 it rolls back the setup and throws...

**Setup Failed**

```
One or more issues caused the setup to fail. Please fix the issues and then retry setup. For more information see the log file.

0x80070643 - Fatal error during installation.
```

and in the log file error message is..

```
Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-user MSI package.
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the WiX toolset. It is described in *[#2677 Start Burn with activated UAC -> insufficient privileges](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3396574&group_id=105970&atid=642714)*.

Comment: I am getting the same issue during my installation.Please refer my SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151665/error-0x80070643-fatal-error-during-installation-wix and guide me.

Comment: @user2725407, the question you mentioned in your comment does not exist. Could you please check the link?